# strange pycharm warning when indexing into a tuple (python)

Tags: python, pycharm

Here is my python code:

```
...
grasses_time = {(0, 0): 0}
last_position = (0, 0)
print last_position[0]
distance_restrictions = []

for time_p in range(len(fjstr)):
    time = time_p + 1
    direction = fjstr[time_p]
    last_position_x = last_position[0]
    last_position_y = last_position[1]
    ...
```

In `last_position_x = last_position[0]`, pycharm gives this warning:
[image: Pycharm error]

Can somebody explain this?

Comment: The explanation is that Pycharm warnings hinder more than they help.

Comment: The warning seems to suggest that it's only applicable in a limited number of use cases. If that console reflects your last run, it seems to have run fine.